# Is it possible to reproduce Quantum interferences with classic code?

Tags: quantum-computing

Whilst I've heard of some quantum emmulators I don't know if I can recreate Quantum interferences (i.e. wave interferences) using them.

Comment: I advise you to provide more details or try to devise a more specific example and ask at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Quantum mechanics may be expensive to simulate, but it is still computable. So: **yes**, you can reproduce quantum interference with a classical simulator.